# Oracle for loop query

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to perform the following in Oracle PL/SQL:

```
BEGIN
  FOR id IN ( 10,200,30,43,5444,6 ) 
    LOOP
        process_the_record ( id );
END LOOP;
END;
```

As this does not seem to work for me.

I basically need to iterate through each of these numbers and pass each number into the procedure, process_the_record (id).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a collection-- you'd just need to call `process_the_record` rather than `dbms_output.put_line`

```
SQL> declare
  2    type num_arr is table of number;
  3    l_ids num_arr := num_arr( 10, 200, 30, 32, 5444, 6 );
  4  begin
  5    for i in 1 .. l_ids.count
  6    loop
  7      dbms_output.put_line( l_ids(i) );
  8    end loop;
  9  end;
 10  /
10
200
30
32
5444
6
```

Answer (score 0):

See the varrays entry [here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/coll/iterate.html).  Will these numbers ever change?  Seems like its an awkward way to do things.